# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection:: Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to get iot to show The items within an order and i keep getting this error

These are my models

```
class westcoorder extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'westcoorders';
    protected $with = 'westcoorderitem';

    protected $fillable = ['is_sent', 'is_delivered'];

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    */
    public function westcoorderitem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\westcoorderitem');
    }
}

class westcoorderitem extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'westcoorderitems';

    protected $fillable = ['westcoorder_id','quantity', 'productName', 'productCode', 'price'];


    public function westcoorder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\westcoorder');
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
public function onGoingOrder($orderNumber)
{
    $orderNumber = westcoorder::where('id', $orderNumber)->firstOrFail();

    $items = westcoorderitem::where('westcoorder_id', $orderNumber)->get();

    return view('westco.onGoingOrder', compact('orderNumber', 'items'));
}
```

And this is what i have in my view

```
<div class="panel-heading">Order @if ($orderNumber) {{ $orderNumber->id }} @endif Items</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                @if($items)
                        {{ $items->productName }}
                @endif
        </div>
```

Here is what my tables looks like

```
Schema::create('westcoorders', function (Blueprint $table)
{
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->tinyInteger('is_sent')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('is_delivered')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
} );

Schema::create('westcoorderitems', function (Blueprint $table)
{
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->Integer('westcoorder_id'); // fk for westcoOrder.id
        $table->string('quantity');
        $table->string('productName');
        $table->string('productCode');
        $table->decimal('price');
        $table->timestamps();
} );
```

And this is the error that I'm getting

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$productName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like your error states:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$productName

You are trying to access a property on a Collection, instead of a Model.
First, you can make use of the relationship you created, like so:

```
$order = App\westcoorder::where('id', $orderNumber)->with('westcoorderitem')->firstOrFail();
```

This will ensure the order items will be included with the result, instead of executing another query to fetch them.

You can then pass on the `$order` to the view:

```
return view('welcome', compact('orderNumber', 'order'));
```

*(You can probably just leave out the orderNumber which was the actual order, as well)*

Then you can access the `order` in your view and loop through the `items` like this:

```
@foreach($order->westcoorderitem as $item)
    {{ $item->productName }}
@endforeach
```

#### FK

Another tip could be to update your table to use indexes to improve performance and make it neat, like the `FK` you mention in the comment of your create migration. You can make a [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) to update it, like:

```
$table->foreign('westcoorder_id')->references('id')->on('westcoorders');
```

And/or expand on this, according to your needs (cascading, etc).

Comment: I have tried that too and I still get the same error it's like the relationship is not working

Comment: @SCRATK I have reproduced your setup and came to this solution, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, looks like this will help, will give it a shot when I get home from work. First time making something like this, work needed it for sending orders out through the email.