# Query returns Object(Builder), undefined property

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel, query-builder

I have following code

```
public function detailCustomer(Customer $customer)
    {
        $vehicles = DB::table('vehicles')
                    ->selectRaw('*')
                    ->where('cust_id', '=', $customer->id);
        return view('customers.detail', array('customer' => $customer, 'vehicles' => $vehicles));
    }
```

Where table `vehicles` consists of:

```
spz
cust_id <FK> //this is foreign key to customer->id
type
brand
```

In the `customers.detail` view, I tried to use following code to show data, but I get this error:

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection::$spz`

Code:

```
@if (count($vehicles) > 0)
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
                           
  @foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle)
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <td>{{$vehicle->spz}}</td>
    <td>{{$vehicle->type}}</td>
    <td>{{$vehicle->brand}}</td>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

I have read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143589/undefined-property-illuminate-database-eloquent-collection-laravel-5-2) but seems it's not my problem because I use `foreach` to iterate through the object but seems I do not get the object from database into my `$vehicles` variable, because in the error page, it shows also something like this:

```
'customer' => object(Customer), 'vehicles' => object(Builder)
```

What makes me think that `customer` gets its object correctly, but `vehicles` gets `Builder`?? Really no idea what is wrong there. Any ideas?
Just to describe what am I doing in the project that I work on, I have a customer detail page where I click a button to add a vehicle to his detail page (profile page) and I send customer `id` as parameter to the function where I add vehicle into database, which works (vehicle is added correctly with the customer `id`). Now that problem shows up when I want to show detail page with vehicle information like the code above shows.
Hope its clear enough. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Does your query not need `->get()` on the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `->get()` or `->paginate($YOUR_LIMIT_ONE_PAGE)` in your Controller

```
public function detailCustomer(Customer $customer)
{
    $vehicles = DB::table('vehicles')
                ->selectRaw('*')
                ->where('cust_id', '=', $customer->id)->get();
                // ->where('cust_id', '=', $customer->id)->paginate($YOUR_LIMIT_ONE_PAGE);
    return view('customers.detail', array('customer' => $customer, 'vehicles' => $vehicles));
}
```

And try to replace your `foreach` to this `forelse`

```
@forelse ($vehicles as $index => $vehicle)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
        <td>{{($vehicle->spz !== null) ? $vehicle->spz : '-'}}</td>
        <td>{{($vehicle->type !== null) ? $vehicle->type : '-'}}</td>
        <td>{{($vehicle->brand !== null) ? $vehicle->brand : '-'}}</td>
   </tr>
@empty
    <td colspan='4'>Data not found</td>
@endforelse
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works! Btw, I did not replace `forelse` but I am assuming its just in case there is no vehicle, correct? And why adding `paginate` makes it working? I don't get it.

Comment: @Ady96 Yes. `forelse` can filter your query is empty or not, bro.

Comment: @Ady96 you can use one of both `get()` you will get all result. and `paginate` you can paging your result. It's make your site not heavy load.

Comment: I know what it does but I dont get why I got that error without `paginate` or `get`.

Comment: @Ady96 If don't have any `paginate` or `get` or `first` or `last`. It's just a query builder. Not result you can get by Object. That's reason. xD