# How to filter taskId regarding to each projectId in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

in My laravel 5.2 application I need print each tasks name in show.blade.php file in tasks folder
tasks/show.blade.php

```
<h2>{{$task->project->project_name}}</h2>
<hr>
{{$task->task_name}}
<hr>
{!!$task->body!!}
<hr>
@include('comments.form')

@include('files.form')
```

this is My taskController show method

```
public function show($id)
 {
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $task = Task::find($id);
    $files = $this->getFiles($id);
return view('tasks.show')->withProject($project)->withFiles($files)->withTask($task);
 }
```

My task table like this way

```
id  task_name  project_id
 1     jui          1
 2     kiu          2
 3     hyu          1
```

but my problem is when I print

```
{{$task->task_name}}
```

here it is always displaying task id no 1 task name only. how can fix this problem?

**Edited**
I need print each task details when I click on each task name on index.blade.php in task folder

index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: No any idea here...

Comment: When you do dd($project->tasks) in the controller, what do you get?

Comment: where should I put **dd($project->tasks)** in the controller

Comment: what do you mean by *it is always displaying task id no 1 task name only.* will you explain with example?

Comment: You are just getting the task with the specified id in your controller. So it is obvious that you just get one task. Change `$task = Task::find($id);` to `$task = Task::all();`

Comment: above comment generate following error **Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$project**

Comment: I mean **it is always displaying task id no 1 task name only** when I click task link 2 or 3 show.blade.php file display only task id 1 task name as an example consider above task table. if I try to see task 3 data then It is show Task 1 data as name **jui**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working fine

in TaskController

```
public function show($project_id,$task_id)
 {
    $project = Project::find($project_id);
    $task = Task::find($task_id);
    $files = $this->getFiles($task_id); // or project_id
return view('tasks.show')->withProject($project)->withFiles($files)->withTask($task);
 }
```

Comment: `$task = Task::find($task_id);` this still just gets one task. You should use `$task = Task::where('task_id', $task_id)->get();` to get all the tasks with a certain task id.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are just getting one task with your query. The task, which has the id you sent to the function also you are mixing normal [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) and [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships).

To set up a relationship between projects and tasks you would do the following. Given that any project can have multiple tasks but one task can always just have one project it would be a one-to-many relationship, which would be set up like this:
**Project.php**

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

**Task.php** (inverse relationship)

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

**TaskController**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $files = $this->getFiles($id);
    $tasks = Project::find(1)->tasks()->where('project_id', $id)->get();

    return view('tasks.show', compact('project', 'files', 'tasks'));
}
```

**View File**

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
  <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $project->tasks->id }}">{{ $project->tasks->task_name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: please see My edited question and see index.blade.php file it is displaying all tasks regarding to each project. when I click each task link I need go show.blade.php file and display other information regarding to relevant task id row.

Comment: **$tasks = Task::where('project_id', $id)->get();** got following message **Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$project**

Comment: @Lilan I updated my answer. Is it working with that code?

Comment: @Lilan I updated my answer once more. You can really solve your own problem by just having a read through the laravel documentation. It is all there!

Comment: please send me that laravel document link

Comment: Also this answer seems to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36143620/4132369